# Apple.com Hot News Headlines

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to mimic the "Hot news headlines" section, is that html 5 or jQuery? It would be great if anyone knows what they use for that.

It has this amazing fade effect that is want I want to go for that really nice timed fade effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [InnerFade](http://medienfreunde.com/lab/innerfade/) plugin for jQuery should do what you need.

Answer (score 2):

It's neither of those. They use [prototype](http://www.prototypejs.org/) and [scriptaculous](http://script.aculo.us/) javascript frameworks. The site loads the [RSS stream with the news](http://www.apple.com/hotnews/feeds/ticker.rss) using AJAX and then uses prototype to parse it and show on the screen. And the continuous news switching is a simple old [window.setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setInterval) call. And [here's the script](http://images.apple.com/home/scripts/ticker.js) itself.

Answer (score 1):

This is fairly easy to do with jQuery.

```
var div = $('#newsdiv').hide(),
    news = ['Top news 1', 'Another top news ', 'Yet another top news'],
    arrl = news.length,
    counter = 0;
function topNews() {
    div.fadeIn(1000).delay(1000).fadeOut(1000, function() {
        topNews();
    }).text(news[counter++]);
    if(arrl<=counter){counter = 0}
}
topNews();
```

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/xxt5F/1/